# Align ListItem Title programatically using Padding or Margin ?? Possible

Tags: android, layout, alignment

I have a listview with two textviews (title) and (subtitle). For some List items i do not have "subtitle" but only "title", in those case how can i align my title in center particularly for those list items programatically. I tried below code, but it was messing layout

[image]

```
if (position == 2) {

                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams)title.getLayoutParams();
                    params.setMargins(0, 10, 0, 0); //substitute parameters for left, top, right, bottom
                    title.setLayoutParams(params);
                }
```

Comment: You should use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.

Comment: I also feel setMargins values are incorrect

Comment: Setting margins will not work perfectly. You should call addRule to the layoutParams.